# Powershell Foreach-Object -Parallel how to change the value of a variable outside the loop (track progress)

Tags: powershell, foreach-object

This code prints a simple progression, doing one thing at a time:

```
$files = 1..100
$i = 0
$files | Foreach-Object {
    $progress = ("#" * $i)
    Write-Host  "`r$progress" -NoNewLine
    $i ++
    Start-Sleep -s 0.1
}
```

But if I want to do two things in parallel at the same time, I can't output the progress because I can't change the variable outside the parallel loops. This doesn't do what's needed:

```
$files = 1..100
$i = 0
$files | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 2 -Parallel {
    $progress = ("#" * $i)
    Write-Host  "`r$progress" -NoNewLine
    $i ++
    Start-Sleep -s 0.1
}
```

I can't find a good solution for accessing an external variable not only to read it with $Using, but also to change it. Is this even possible in Powershell 7?

Comment: One option is to only track progress for things you can observe "from the outside", ie. "X out of Y parallel jobs have completed"

Comment: There's a doc about displaying the progress of multiple threads if you want to go through the trouble with a thread safe hashtable:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/write-progress-across-multiple-threads?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: @js2010  Yeah, I've seen this. It's not exactly what I need. Honestly, I don't really understand how it works with sync hashtable. In my case there is a list of files and I need to do heavy encoding for each file. My computer can handle 2 encoding processes at the same time. And I only need to show overall progress of the number of already finished files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is right, based on [Writing Progress across multiple threads with Foreach Parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/write-progress-across-multiple-threads?view=powershell-7.1).  [It may be missing a lock](https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/thread-synchronization-in-powershell/), but just for writing progress it's probably not a big deal.  In this case you can just use the filename for the progress too.

```
$hash = @{i = 1}
$sync = [System.Collections.Hashtable]::Synchronized($hash)

$files = 1..100
$files | Foreach-Object -throttlelimit 2 -parallel {
    $syncCopy = $using:sync
    $progress = '#' * $syncCopy.i
    #$progress = '#' * $_
    Write-Host  "`r$progress" -NoNewLine
    $syncCopy.i++
    Start-Sleep .1
}
```

Output:

```
####################################################################################################
```

Comment: This appears to be flawed, at least in the current version of Powershell 7. If I change it to add `Write-Host $syncCopy.i` I get `1 1 3 3 5 5 7 8 9 9 11 11 13`.

Answer (score 8):

Per this article - [PowerShell ForEach-Object Parallel Feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) - you can reference variables from the "outer" script using the `$using` keyword:

e.g.

```
$files = 1..100
$i = 100;
$files | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 2 -Parallel {
    write-host ($using:i)
    Start-Sleep -s .1
}
# 100
# 100
# etc
```

But if you try to update the value you'll get this:

```
$files | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 2 -Parallel {
    $using:i += $using:i
    Start-Sleep -s .1
}

ParserError:
Line |
   2 |      $using:i += $using:i
     |      ~~~~~~~~
     | The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept
     | assignments, such as a variable or a property.
```

Basically, you can't assign *back* to the `$using:i` variable.

What you *could* do is mutate the properties of a complex object instead - e.g. this:

```
$counter = @{ "i" = 0 }
$files | Foreach-Object -ThrottleLimit 2 -Parallel {
     ($using:counter).i = ($using:counter).i + 1
     Start-Sleep -s .1
}
$counter

# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# i                              100
#
```

which lets you update the value, but may not (probably won't be) be thread-safe.

Comment: `$counter = @{ "i" = 0 }` - Yes, it works. Although it looks like a kind of hacking when you do things you shouldn't do.

Comment: Typo: `$using:i += $usinge:i`

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with larger values of `-ThrottleLimit` (say 4+), using a synchronized queue (for thread safety), `Write-Progress`, and jobs can be a nice solution for tracking progress. As others have mentioned, the `$Using` keywords allows you access to variables within a scriptblock scope:

```
$files = 1..100
$queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::new()
1..$files.Count | ForEach-Object { $queue.Enqueue($_) }
$syncQueue = [System.Collections.Queue]::synchronized($queue)

$job = $files | ForEach-Object -AsJob -ThrottleLimit 6 -Parallel {
    $sqCopy = $Using:syncQueue
    #Simulating work...do stuff with files here
    Start-Sleep (Get-Random -Maximum 10 -Minimum 1)

    #Dequeue element to update progress
    $sqCopy.Dequeue()
}

#While $job is running, update progress bar
while ($job.State -eq 'Running') {
    if ($syncQueue.Count -gt 0) {
        $status = ((1 / $syncQueue.Count) * 100)
        Write-Progress -Activity "Operating on Files" -Status "Status" -PercentComplete $status
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }
}
```

In my experience, using a synchronized hashtable was too messy for several threads; I wanted a single, clean progress bar. It depends on your use case though. Thought I'd add my piece to the other excellent answers.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution with thead-safe dictionaries on https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/. I think this is at the moment the safest solution:

```
$threadSafeDictionary = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string,object]]::new()
Get-Process | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $dict = $using:threadSafeDictionary
    $dict.TryAdd($_.ProcessName, $_)
}

$threadSafeDictionary["pwsh"]
```