# Powershell Foreach-Object parallel with az cli profile isolation

Tags: azure, parallel-processing, azure-cli, foreach-object, powershell-7.2

I have a script that need to call child scripts in parallel. Child scripts using az cli and create/modify Azure PaaS objects in different Azure subscriptions. 
The problem is that as different scripts are using `az account set --subscription <subscription-for-script>`, they overlap and something that need to be created in subscription A by script A, created in subscription B cause a moment before script B set subscription to subscription B.
As az cli stores context in AzureProfile.json, I tried to create new folder per script and via `$Env:AZURE_CONFIG_DIR` specify different values per script. But I cannot find a way to isolate environment variables in child scripts, or specify AzureProfile context without using environment variables.
In parent script:

```
$listOfScripts | Foreach-Object -Parallel {
  <block to run script with arguments>
} -AsJob -ThrottleLimit 50
```

and in each child script:

```
$Env:AZURE_CONFIG_DIR = "$RootPath\..\AzureProfiles\folderForScript"
az login --service-principal -u ${env:ARM_CLIENT_ID} -p ${env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET} --tenant ${env:ARM_TENANT_ID}
az account set --subscription $subscription_id
```

Would be appreciate for advice how could be achieved running parallel independent scripts that uses different subscriptions to modify Azure PaaS objects

**Update:** Only solution that found - not to use `az login` and `az account set` inside scripts that run in parallel. Just connect via SPN in parent script and use parameter `--subscription` in each az command.

Answer (score 0):

#### Run script block in parallel

Script blocks run in a **runspace** context in a PowerShell. It contains all the **defined variables, functions & loaded modules**. Initializing a **runspace** for **script** to run in takes time and resources. It must be run within their **own runspace** when scripts are running in parallel. Each **runspace** must ***load*** whatever **module is needed** and have any **variable be explicitly passed** in from the calling script.

**The only variable that automatically appears in the parallel script block is the piped in object. Other variables are passed in using the `$using:` keyword.**

#### Example

```
$computers =  'computerA','computerB','computerC','computerD' 
$logsToGet =  'LogA','LogB','LogC'  
# Read specified logs on each machine, using custom module 
$logs = $computers |  ForEach-Object  -ThrottleLimit  10  -Parallel  {  
Import-Module  MyLogsModule  
Get-Logs  -ComputerName $_ -LogName $using:logsToGet 
}
```

#### References

- [PowerShell ForEach-object -parallel Feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/)
- [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570734/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-how-to-change-the-value-of-a-variable-outsid) for implementation