# How to return a list from ForEach-Object in powershell 7.2.1

Tags: powershell

I have a library of Powershell 5.1 scripts and I want to rewrite some of them in Powershell 7.2.1. Mainly because of the new parallel execution of ForEach-Object.

Here is simplified example of script written in Powershell 5.1 that Test-Connection ForEach-Object in $computers list and add pc either to $OnlinePc list or $OfflinePc list.

```
$color = "Gray"
$Major = ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).Major
$Minor = ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).Minor
Write-Host "My Powershell version: " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $color
Write-Host "$Major.$Minor"
Write-Host

$computers = @(
    '172.30.79.31',
    '172.30.79.32',
    '172.30.79.33',
    '172.30.79.34',
    '172.30.79.35',
    '172.30.79.36',
    '172.30.79.37'
)

Write-Host "List of all computers:" -ForegroundColor $color
$computers

foreach ($pc in $computers) {
    if (Test-Connection -Count 1 $pc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $OnlinePc+=$pc
    }
    else {
        $OfflinePc+=$pc
    }
}

Write-Host
Write-Host "List of online computers:" -ForegroundColor $color
$OnlinePc

Write-Host
Write-Host "List of offline computers:" -ForegroundColor $color
$OfflinePc

Write-Host
pause
```

And here is same script rewtitten in Powershell 7.2.1

```
$color = "Gray"
$Major = ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).Major
$Minor = ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).Minor
$Patch = ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).Patch
Write-Host "My Powershell version: " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $color
Write-Host "$Major.$Minor.$Patch"
Write-Host

$computers = @(
    '172.30.79.31',
    '172.30.79.32',
    '172.30.79.33',
    '172.30.79.34',
    '172.30.79.35',
    '172.30.79.36',
    '172.30.79.37'
)

Write-Host "List of all computers:" -ForegroundColor $color
$computers

$computers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    if (Test-Connection -Count 1 $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $OnlinePc+=$_
    }
    else {
        $OfflinePc+=$_
    }
}

Write-Host
Write-Host "List of online computers:" -ForegroundColor $color
$OnlinePc

Write-Host
Write-Host "List of offline computers:" -ForegroundColor $color
$OfflinePc

Write-Host
pause
```

Here is picture of output from both scripts.

[Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Zmj.png)

I tried to edit the ForEach-Object syntax in many ways, but I can't get it to work the same way it worked in 5.1, any tips would be apperacited.

PS: Computers 172.30.79.32 and 172.30.79.33 are offline, the others are online.

Comment: Don't use `+=` to add to an array (which you haven't even declared). Use [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) objects that have an `.Add()` method. Also applies to PowerShell 5.1

Comment: Scriptblocks in a ```foreach-object -parallel``` are executed in isolated runspaces - see this question for how to modify variables in the main script’s scope… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570734/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-how-to-change-the-value-of-a-variable-outsid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commenters noted, script blocks in a `ForEach-Object -Parallel` don't have direct access to surrounding variables as they run in isolated *runspaces*.

While you could use the `$using` keyword to work around this situation (as show in [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570734/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-how-to-change-the-value-of-a-variable-outsid)), a more **idiomatic approach** is to capture the output of `ForEach-Object` in a variable. This automatically produces an array if more than one objects are output. By storing the online state in a property, we can later split that array to get two separate lists for online and offline PCs.

```sh
$computerState = $computers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Host = $_
        Online = Test-Connection -Count 1 $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Quiet
    }
}

Write-Host
Write-Host "List of online computers:" -ForegroundColor $color
$computerState.Where{ $_.Online -eq $true }.Host

Write-Host
Write-Host "List of offline computers:" -ForegroundColor $color
$computerState.Where{ $_.Online -eq $false }.Host
```

**Notes:**

- `[pscustomobject]@{…}` dynamically creates an object and *implicitly* outputs it, which gets captured in `$computerState`, automatically creating an array if necessary. This is more efficient than using the array `+=` operator, which has to reallocate and copy the array elements for each new element to be added, because arrays are actually of fixed size ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60708578/7571258)).
- Parameter `-Quiet` is used so that `Test-Connection` outputs a `[bool]` value to be stored in the `Online` property.
- `.Where{…}` is an [intrinsic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#where) that PowerShell provides for all objects. Similarly to `Where-Object` it acts as a filter, but is faster and the syntax is more succinct.
- Finally by writing `.Host` we make use of PowerShell's convenient [member access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) feature, which creates an array from the `Host` property of the filtered `$computerState` items.

Answer (score 2):

When using `ForEach-Object -Parallel` each object is processed in a different runspace and thread (as mentioned by mclayton in a comment).  Variables are not accessible across runspaces in most cases.  Below are 2 possible alternative ways to use -Parallel

The following code does not assign or use any variables inside the `Foreach-Object -Parallel` block.  Instead online computers are assigned to a variable outside.

```
$computers = @(
    'localhost',
    'www.google.com',
    'notarealcomputer',
    'www.bing.com',
    'www.notarealwebsitereally.com'
)

# Assign the output of foreach-object command directly into a variable rather than assigning variables inside
$onlinePc = $computers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $_ | Where-Object { Test-Connection -Count 1 -Quiet $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
}

# determine offline computers by checking which are not in $onlinePc
$offlinePc = $computers | Where-Object { $_ -notin $onlinePc }

Write-Host '--- Online ---' -ForegroundColor Green
$onlinePc
Write-Host
Write-Host '--- Offline ---' -ForegroundColor Red
$offlinePc
```

---

This next method uses a [synchronized hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized?view=net-6.0) and the [$using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7.2) to collect the data inside the -Parallel block

```
$computers = @(
    'localhost',
    'www.google.com',
    'notarealcomputer',
    'www.bing.com',
    'www.notarealwebsitereally.com'
)

# Create a hashtable containing empty online and offline lists
$results = @{
    'online'  = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
    'offline' = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
}

# thread-safe wrapped hashtable
$syncResults = [hashtable]::Synchronized($results)

$computers | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    if ($_ | Test-Connection -Quiet -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        ($using:syncResults).online.add($_)
    }
    else {
        ($using:syncResults).offline.add($_)
    }
}

$results
```

Output

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
online                         {localhost, www.bing.com, www.google.com}
offline                        {www.notarealwebsitereally.com, notarealcomputer}
```

---

I do not claim to be an expert.  There are likely better ways to do this.  Just thought I'd share a couple that I know.